# getting positional arguments in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script called foo with variable number of arguments, with the first one being a required one, i.e.:

```
foo a1 b2 b3 b4 ...
```

I understand that in bash $1 will get me argument a1, but is there a way to get all the rest of the arguments? $@ or $* seem to get me all the arguments including a1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slice the `$@` array.

```
echo "${@:2}"
```

Comment: In case someone else is wondering: the special `$@` array starts with index *1*, whereas regular bash arrays are (by default) 0-based. Applying `shift` once (as suggested by other answers) would allow direct use of `$@` without the need to slice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shift](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) command for that. That will remove $1 and you can access the rest of arguments starting with $1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $*
shift
echo $*
```

`shift` will shift all the parameters, running the previous example would give:

```
$ test_shift.sh a b c d e
a b c d e
b c d e
```

Answer (score 0):

./foo.sh 1 2 3 4

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1;
echo $2;
echo $3;
echo $4;
```

Will output:

```
1
2
3
4
```